# Determining prime ideals lying above a given ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$, where
>   $$f(x)=x^4+42x^3-11x^2+22x-2002002002002002.$$ Let $I=3R$, the ideal
>   generated by $3$ in $R$. Find all prime ideals of $R$ that contain
>   $I$.

I am hoping to get some feedback on the following proposed solution.

Using the lattice theorem for prime ideals, we can translate the problem into one that asks for all prime ideals lying above $q^{-1}(3R)$, where 
$$q:\mathbb Z[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$$
is the quotient map. This means we want to find all primes lying above $(3,f)$, or equivalently (reducing $f$ mod $3$) all primes lying above
$$(3,x(x^3+x+1)).$$
From the classification of prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[x]$, we know any prime ideals look like $(f)$ for irreducible $f$, $(p)$, for $(p,f)$, where in the last case $f$ is irreducible mod $p$. So then the only primes above $I$ are $(3,x)$ and $(3,x^3+x+1).$

Is this correct?

Edit: A helpful commenter (@Andrey) pointed out that $x^3+x+1=(x-1)(x^2+x-1)$ mod $3$. So the answer should be 
$(3,x)$, $(3,x-1)$, and $(3,x^2+x+2).$

Comment: $x^3+x+1$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_3.$

Comment: $x^3+x+1 = (x+2)(x^2+x+2)$

Comment: @Andrey Sorry about that! I think it is fixed.